# What is the proper name for "AM" and "PM"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, time, hypernyms

I know that AM/PM is for ante/post meridiem, but what is it actually called? Meridian indicator? 12 hour indicator? Something way more clever?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

## Answer

Oddly enough, this question seems to already have been answered (and then later removed) [at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468857/what-is-am-pm-called).
([this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180223061132/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468857/what-is-am-pm-called) is the last existing Wayback Machine backup link to it.)

- The [Unicode standard for date/time formatting](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) calls it "*period*".
- [Wikipedia](https://web.archive.org/web/20180314144118/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) says: The 12-hour clock is a time conversion convention in which the 24 hours of the day are divided into two *periods*
- Ruby documentation (and probably a lot of strftime references) seems to refer them as "*Meridiem Indicator*".

From a user interface perspective, a "*Period*" label is too ambiguous, and "*Meridiem Indicator*" too pedantic, still leaving "*AM/PM*" as the best choice.

## Aside

As for the actual meanings of AM/PM, they come from the Latin "ante meridiem" ("before noon") and "post meridiem" ("after noon").

Comment: ha! wtf... why would that be asked on SO? anyways, thanks!

Comment: any comment on 'ante-meridian'?

Comment: @Jason, because software developers think about naming variables properly. It is built into the Object-Oriented mindset. Jader, a commenter, said it well: "It's funny that the question intrinsically is not programming related, but all programmers can understand why you posted it here."

Comment: @rajah9 this is actually why i asked this question in the first place ;)

Comment: @Json and that was the reason I found your post XD

Comment: The deleted SO post suggests "Meridiem Indicator" as an alternate term that is less ambiguous than "period"

Comment: @rajah9 That's why I'm here :). I wanted to properly name my variable.

Comment: Also here to properly name a variable. :)

Comment: interesting answer, but you don't cite any sources for why that is an accepted or generally valid term to use for it

Comment: > leaving "AM/PM" as the best choice

Not exactly so, IMO. 
In German it's nachts ("at night") & morgens ("in the morning").
And, in Japanese, it can be written 午後 (gogo, afternoon; P.M.) & 午前 (gozen, morning; A.M.) (before the time values).
I think I will use `meridiem` or `meridiemIndicator`.