# Is there a word to encompass the two states of a day: AM and PM, morning and afternoon?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

A single word which sums up the option of AM/PM or morning/afternoon.

Comment: Depending on the context, I've seen the following used to good effect: "day or night", "on that date", "during that 24-hour period".

Comment: Exact duplicate of [A single term for the duration between sunrise and sunset?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/237596).

Comment: Another dup: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35315/what-is-the-proper-name-for-am-and-pm which suggests "period" or "Meridiem Indicator"

Answer (score 1):

[Daytime](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/daytime) is usually used to refer to the part of the day that comprises morning and afternoon:

> - the time between dawn and dusk; the day ***as distinct from evening or night.***

Collins Dictionary