# The history of the English "postmeridian"

Tags: etymology, orthography, suffixes, latin, loanwords

There's a [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/152603/why-is-11-am-1-hour-1200-pm) on English Language Learners that's been making the rounds recently, it's been on the *Hot Network Questions* list since January 5 this year and has attracted something like 36,000 views (all credit to tchrist's exhaustive and flawless answer for this extraordinary phenomenon).

I posted an answer, and from a comment, it seems I've done something terribly wrong, but I don't understand what exactly.

Until January 5, I believed that PM, P.M., p.m. or pm was short for *post meridian* and that it was spelled as two separate words. That's how I've always pronounced it. but it was pointed out to me that the correct Latin spelling is ***post meridiem***. So, I edit the post and add the following reflection

> … in English spelled **postmeridian** [emphasis mine].

Shortly after, a user posted the following comment

> 'Postmeridian' (single word, no space) may be English (although it is certainly antiquated by 'afternoon') but 'P.M.' is an abbreviation for the Latin phrase '***p***ost **m**eridiem'. There is no 'English spelling' of Latin phrases, there are only translations, but even then 'postmeridian' is actually worse of a translation than 'after noon', because of its archaic status. […]

Was I that wrong to say that ‘post meridiem’ is spelled ‘postmeridian’ in English? Is *postmeridian* an English translation? That doesn't make much sense to me, it looks very much like a loanword that's been *anglicized* (?) not translated.

The following definitions are from *Merriam-Webster*

**post meridiem**
adjective : [being after noon —abbreviation *PM*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/post%20meridiem)
First Known Use: 1647

**postmeridian**
adjective : [occurring after noon : of or relating to the afternoon the postmeridian hours of the day](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/postmeridian)
Origin and Etymology
Latin *postmeridianus*, from post- + *meridianus* meridian

- Can someone explain if the original Latin expression consists two words and is spelled “post meri**diem**”, why is it spelled as a single word in English with a different suffix, [dian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dian), *postmeri**dian***?
- Is *postmeridian* (or post meridian) a bastardization?
- What is the history of the word *postmeridian* and its spelling?

---

Related (*paullum*) [What is the proper name for "AM" and "PM"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35315/what-is-the-proper-name-for-am-and-pm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a (post-classical) Latin word *postmeridianum* from the 6ᵗʰ century that meant “after midday” which English first borrowed directly as *postmeridian* no later than 1583.

The OED says this of its history:

> As noun < post-classical Latin *postmeridianum* the hours after midday, afternoon (6th cent.), use as noun (short for classical Latin *postmerīdiānum* *tempus* the time after midday) of neuter of classical Latin *postmerīdiānus*, adjective; as adjective < classical Latin *postmerīdiānus* (also in contracted form *pōmerīdiānus*) (adjective) of or occurring in the afternoon < *post* after (see *post*- prefix) + *merīdiēs* midday (see *meridian* adj.) + -*ānus* -*an* suffix (compare *merīdiānus* meridian adj.). With use as adjective compare *antemeridian* adj., and earlier *pomeridian* adj. With geological senses (see senses A. 2, B. 2) compare *premeridian* adj. In use as adverb perhaps erroneously for *post meridiem* adv.

The word *postmeridian* is now mainly used as an adjective:

> Of or relating to the afternoon; occurring after noon or midday.

It also clocks in as a rare noun meaning

> The hours after midday, the afternoon. Chiefly *fig*. Now *rare*.

Here’s one citation for that use:

> **1969**   *Hispanic Rev*. 37 208 —  The high noon of Charles the Fifth had declined into the somber post-meridian of Philip II.

The word is also sometimes used as an adverb meaning in or during the afternoon. For example:

> **1996**   *New Eng. Q.* 69 397 —  Turkey's ire builds up through the morning and, post-meridian, is vented.

Comment: But is "postmeridian" an English translation? Can we call it that?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I wouldn't call it a “translation”, *per se*. It's just lost its *-us* suffix, but that happens all the time. It’s a loanword.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Why the 6ᵗʰ century scholars created Latin *postmeridianus* as an adjective for the prepositional phrase *post meridiem* is probably something better suited to [latin.se] but I’ll ask around.

Comment: So what's the difference in meaning between *post meridiem* and *postmeridianum*?

Comment: *post meridiem* is a prepositional phrase, normally used adverbially. *postmeridianus* is the corresponding adjective. *postmeridianum* is the neuter form of the adjective used as a noun

Comment: @Mari-LouA Anglo-Norman French had *meridien* < Latin *meridiem* for midday, noon, but this was reinforced by awareness of Latin in English scholars. We ended up spelling that *meridian* in English after a spell.  The OED has a longish write-up about all that business. There’s also *meridional* meaning south contrasting with *septentrional* meaning north.

Comment: So both  "*a stroll post meridiem*" and "*a postmeridian stroll*" would be acceptable?

Comment: @Mari-LouA They **should** be, yes.

Comment: It's nice to have N/S counterparts to oriental and occidental.