# When did 'post' become a popular replacement of the word 'after'

Tags: popularity

I am trying to determine when 'post' became a popular replacement of the word 'after'.

I have found 'post' being prefixed to words used in the medical and other professional disciplines, and in academic works in the 1800s.  However, I am trying to determine when it became common to use it as a replacement.  (Eg, using 'post-emancipation' rather than 'after emancipation')

I am also trying to determine when it started to be introduced in text books for 12 and 13 year old students.

Comment: I think that [*post* comes from latin](https://www.etymonline.com/word/post-), and [*after* comes from Germanic](https://www.etymonline.com/word/after), so it may actually be the other way around. [Latin is technically older than Germanic?](https://www.quora.com/Which-language-is-older-Latin-or-German). I don't think either is a replacement of the other though.

Comment: Yes, 'post' comes from Latin.  However, I am trying to find out when it became popular.  When was it common to talk about "post-war" rather than "after the war".

Comment: I'd guess the "biggie" is ***post-war***. Which according to [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=postwar%2Cpost-war&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpostwar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpost%20-%20war%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpostwar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpost%20-%20war%3B%2Cc0) was already gaining traction after WW1 (perhaps people thought ***post-war years*** was more "optimistic" than ***Depression***). But it really got moving *during* WW2 (with many anticipatory references to "post-war planning"). And all academia became ***post-modernist***.

Comment: 'Post' is useful in premodifiers. 'The after-war period' sounds unwieldy.

Comment: Yes, but you need not say, "the after-war period".   Instead, you can simply say, "after the war ..."

Comment: @Walbrent Those two constructions have slightly different implications. "Post-war" tends to mean the period and things that happened or were developed in that period whether or not the war caused or influenced the occurrences or developments. "After the war" tends to mean things that resulted or were strongly affected by the war. Also "after the war" usually means a shorter period than "post war". For example "There was a need for building reconstruction after the war" and "Post-war building techniques were different from the ones used earlier"

Comment: You'd have to refer to the post-war era as the after-the-war period without using post-. Also see [postmeridian/postmeridiem](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425901/the-history-of-the-english-postmeridian) for a usage of post- from way back

Answer (score 3):

post-,  a prefix    [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/148402#eid28944942)

> Formations with second elements not of Latin or Greek origin are first
>   found in the 17th or 18th centuries (e.g. in the 17th cent. perhaps
>   **post-talmudical** adj. at sense 2a(b)(iv)(1) and **post-law** n. at sense 1a(b)(ii)(2), in the 18th cent. **post-breakfast** adj. at sense
>   2a(a)(i), post-Kantian n. and adj. at sense 2a(b)(i)); **such
>   formations become particularly common in the 20th cent**.

It appears using the post- prefix with the following noun being English appeared in the 14th century **and became most common in the 1900+ period**. I even see a listing for post 16, ie after the age of 16 years old.

> Formations after Latin models first appear in English in the late 14th
>   cent. (in an apparently isolated attestation: post-common n.) and then
>   again from the 16th cent. (e.g. post-dissension n., postbrachial adj.
>   at sense 2b); the first direct borrowing from Latin is apparently
>   **postpone** v. in the late 15th cent.; there are also some borrowings
>   from Middle French before the end of the 16th cent. (e.g.
>   post-communion n., postpose v.). From the end of the 16th cent., most
>   formations are within English, although there are still a number of
>   borrowings directly from Latin (e.g. postpredicament n., postscribe
>   v.) and formations after Latin models.

Comment: The post prefix was common in academic literature at that time.  But when did it become common in popular literature.

Comment: as cited ... the 1900's